# Adding RAM changed UUID of Luks partition (Linux Mint 20.1)

Tags: linux-mint, mount, luks, cryptsetup

This is one of the weirdest glitches I've ever encountered. I have (3) partitions encrypted with Luks:

```
/home           (on same disk as root)
/media/backups  (external USB drive)
swap            (on same disk as root)
```

After adding (2) 8 GB DDR4 sticks - same exact RAM/manufacturer as the (2) original 8 GB sticks - I rebooted and checked the BIOS to see if everything was being seen. That verified, I continued to boot...and `/home` would not mount. I dropped to a console login and tried to manually unlock/mount `/home` - worked perfectly. Confused, I logged in to my XFCE session and checked for errors in the boot logs - nothing. Then I verified my `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab` for errors - again nothing. Then I ran `lsblk` and discovered that my system had decided to change the UUID of my (locked) Luks partition that mapped to `/home`:

**Original**

```
$ cat /.snapshots/106/snapshot/etc/crypttab
# <target>      <source device>                             <key file>      <options>
crypthome       UUID=d0600294-3424-42c9-a0f3-b1ba222737c6   none            luks,discard
cryptswap       UUID=92c9487d-2b69-40cc-bc22-13af29703735   /dev/urandom    luks,discard
cryptbackups    UUID=d821353b-ac43-41a7-bf53-f65a030895c7   none            luks
```

**New (fixed)**

```
$ cat /etc/crypttab
# <target>      <source device>                             <key file>      options>
crypthome       UUID=9daed737-e5d3-4a96-8260-8b024c2c13fa   none            luks,discard
cryptswap       UUID=92c9487d-2b69-40cc-bc22-13af29703735   /dev/urandom    luks,discard
cryptbackups    UUID=d821353b-ac43-41a7-bf53-f65a030895c7   none            luks
```

None of the other Luks partitions suffered this change. Is this normal?